# UIView on UITableViewCell updating without animating

Tags: swift

I had a regression and I don't know what could have caused it.

**Desired**: smooth animation[image]

**Current**: update without animation. [image]

Here is the code that caused the break. I don't know why.

```
    var pillModel: PillModel? {
        didSet {
            guard let pillModel = pillModel else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.movePill(pillModel.side)
            }
            movingPill.backgroundColor = pillModel.movingPillColor
            leftLabel.textColor = pillModel.leftLabelColor
            rightLabel.textColor = pillModel.rightLabelColor
            leftLabel.text = pillModel.leftTekst
            rightLabel.text = pillModel.rightTekst
            movingPill.layer.applySketchShadow(color: movingPill.backgroundColor!, alpha: 0.7, y: 3)
            pillContainer.layoutSubviews()
            commonStyle()
        }
    }
```

Here is some relevant code.

```
    func movePill( _ sideTouched: Side, _ completion: (() -> ())? = nil) {
        constrainPillTo(sideTouched)
        pillModel?.side = sideTouched
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.85, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.65, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            [weak self] in
            guard let selfy = self else {return}
            selfy.movingPill.backgroundColor = .orange//selfy.pillModel?.movingPillColor
            selfy.leftLabel.textColor = .yellow//selfy.pillModel?.leftLabelColor
            selfy.rightLabel.textColor = .green//selfy.pillModel?.rightLabelColor
            selfy.movingPill.layer.applySketchShadow(color: selfy.movingPill.backgroundColor ?? .socialBlue,
                                                     alpha: 0.7, y: 3)
            //selfy.pillContainer.layoutSubviews()
        }) { _ in
            completion?()
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan  How should I present changes as text?

Comment: Is `cellForRowAt` getting called when you tap? It looks like you are creating a new cell now instead of grabbing a persistent one?

Comment: @Joe, That's a great thought, however I'm not calling `cellforrowat`...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I created a cycle. When I moved the code out of the `pillModel` property's `didSet` method into its own function, the issue was resolved completely.